# Cannot see my controllers actions in the Swagger UI

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

I am trying to setup my web api project to use Swagger.

I installed Swashbuckle and while the Swagger UI works when I go to `http://localhost:55010/swagger`, I see none of my controllers actions.

[image]

I am using this kind of path for my actions: `http://localhost:55010/api/v1/Role`

I currently have only one version of my api, but I am planning to have more than one so I am using `v1` in my URL paths (it is set up by using subfolders in my Controllers folder).

Here is what I see when I go to `http://localhost:55010/swagger/docs/v1`:

```
{"swagger":"2.0","info":{"version":"v1","title":"Swashbuckle Dummy API V1"},"host":"localhost:55010","schemes":["http"],"paths":{},"definitions":{}}
```

This is the configuration that I am using:

```
public class SwaggerConfig
{
    public static void Register()
    {
        var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration 
            .EnableSwagger(c =>
                {
                    c.MultipleApiVersions(
                        (apiDesc, targetApiVersion) => ResolveVersionSupportByRouteConstraint(apiDesc, targetApiVersion),
                        (vc) =>
                        {
                            //vc.Version("v2", "Swashbuckle Dummy API V2");
                            vc.Version("v1", "Swashbuckle Dummy API V1");
                        });
                })
            .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
                {
                });
    }

    private static bool ResolveVersionSupportByRouteConstraint(ApiDescription apiDesc, string targetApiVersion)
    {
        // I don't know how I am supposed to use this
        return true;
    }
}
```

My Route config :

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "WithActionApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{folder}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { action = @"[A-Za-z]+" }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{folder}/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { action = "DefaultAction", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

and one example of a controller :

```
public class GridTemplateController : BaseController
{
    GridTemplateLogic logic;

    public GridTemplateController(IPermissionValidator permissionValidator, IRolePermissionLogic logicRolePermission)
        : base(permissionValidator, logicRolePermission)
    {
        logic = new GridTemplateLogic(new GridTemplateRepository(ConnectionString, CurrentUser), permissionValidator);
    }

    // GET: api/v1/GridTemplate/ForGrid/5
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult ForGrid(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            var entityList = logic.GetAllByGridId(id);
            return Ok(new ApiResponse(entityList));
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            return Unauthorized();
        }
    }

    ...........
```

Comment: Can you add the route configuration and (a part of) your controller to the question?

Comment: @venerik yes I just added them. Thanks!

Comment: Is the `BaseController` derived from `ApiController` and does your API work? E.g. if you do `GET /api/v1/GridTemplate/ForGrid/5` you get the expected result?

Comment: @venerik Yes and yes :) the web api works correctly

Comment: I'm sorry. I can't see what's wrong... :(

Answer (score 1):

Change swagger configuration to this:

```
public class SwaggerConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    ...
}
```

And configure it after all the other configurations:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ...
        SwaggerConfig.Register(config);
    }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure he's not using ASP.Net Core **Edit** I had no idea this was a very old question. I gotta learn how to look up at the dates.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the [AcceptVerbs("xxx")] on my methods and they appeared in my Swagger :-)

Comment: Thanks @florian. I had the same issue. The only thing which worked for me was by replacing [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")] with [HttpGet("GetWeatherForecast")]